# Junit/Java create test method for void with exception

Tags: java, junit

I want to create a test method for this void method:

```
/**
* @param speler speler die zijn wedstrijdronde heeft afgemaakt
* @param score  score van de speler
* @throws GeenSpelerException als de persoon geen speler is
*/
@Override
public void scoreToPar(Speler speler, int score) throws GeenSpelerException {
    if (speler.speeltWedstrijd(this.spelers,speler)) //boolean
    {
        throw new GeenSpelerException();
    }
    speler.setScore(score); // set score into player
```

I've made this test method for it:

```
@Test
void scoreToParTest() throws GeenSpelerException {
    wed.isIngeschreven(speler); // add speler to first list
    wed.isSpeler(); // add speler from first list to second list (to spelers list)
    wed.scoreToPar(speler, 70);
    assertEquals(70, speler.getScore()); // check if the score was set correctly
}
```

But when I run the test it says test failed and throws the exception.
When I run the first method in my main it does exactly what I want but in the test it fails...

How can I write a good test for this method?

If it helps this is the boolean method that is checked in the if of the method I want to test.

```
@Override
public boolean speeltWedstrijd(List<Speler> spelers, Participant participant) {
    return spelers.contains(participant);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if I didn't understand your code intentions, but based on your code comments, it seems your test code will throw an error as,

```
wed.isSpeler(); // add speler from first list to second list (to spelers list)
```

which will add **speler** to **spelers** list

So speeltWedstrijd will return contains True and scoreToPar will throw **GeenSpelerException** exception.

As suggested by JekBP, you can use code to handle exception, but based on your comment, it seems you are using Junit 5, which has more powerful **assertThrows** like,

```
@Test
void scoreToParTest()
    Assertions.assertThrows(GeenSpelerException.class, () -> {
        wed.isIngeschreven(speler); // add speler to first list
        wed.isSpeler(); // add speler from first list to second list (to spelers list)
        wed.scoreToPar(speler, 70);    
    }); 
}
```

I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use mock as in [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/):

```
@Test
void scoreToParTest() throws GeenSpelerException {
    var speler = mock(Speler.class);

    wed.scoreToPar(speler, 70);

    verify(speler).setScore(70);
}
```

You verify that `scoreToPar` is effectively doing what it should: set the score to the value it should.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this annotation in your test class's test method so that it will pass the test once the expected exception GeenSpelerException is indeed thrown.

```
 @Test(expected = GeenSpelerException.class)
    void scoreToParTest() throws GeenSpelerException {
        wed.isIngeschreven(speler); // add speler to first list
        wed.isSpeler(); // add speler from first list to second list (to spelers list)
        wed.scoreToPar(speler, 70);
        assertEquals(70, speler.getScore()); // check if the score was set correctly
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but when I add in the expected I get an red line under expected and it says "cannot resolve method expected"

Comment: @RonnyGiezen it seems you are using Junit5 which has assertThrows