# Why jUnit 5 doesn't see my exception test?

Tags: java, testing, exception, junit

I've written 48 test methods to test my course assignment. None of them is an exceptional test but they are working correctly.

Finally, I tried to test my own exceptions, JUnit 5 doesn't see it. There are some examples of my code design and exception test.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class Final_Tests extends TestCase {
    
    @Test
    public static void testD4_setChair() {
    Department testD = new Department("CSE 101","CSE 101!");
    Teacher testT = new Teacher("Ali","Veli.com",testD,"CV");
    testD.setChair(testT);
    assertEquals(testT,testD.getChair());
}
```

There is no problem with testing non-exception methods.

The problem is here:

```
@Test 
public static void DepartmentMismatchException_Test() {
Department testD = new Department("CSE 101","CSE 101!");
Teacher testT = new Teacher("Mehmet", "mehmet.com", testD, "CV Mehmet");
Course testC1 = new Course(testD,101,"Test Course 1","Test Course 1 Desc.",testT,6);
String expMsg = "DepartmentMismatchException: Teacher in " + testT.getDepartment().getCode()+ ", Course in " +testC1.getDepartment().getCode();
    
DepartmentMismatchException dme =  new DepartmentMismatchException(testT.getDepartment(), testC1.getDepartment());
    assertEquals(expMsg, dme.toString());
}
```

Is a problem with code design like usage of scopes, static or other modifiers, or about my exception test codes?

Comment: I believe exception testing means testing that, under the conditions where your object should throw an exception, it does, indeed, throw the expected exception.

Comment: Enes, please check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374907/4719944. You can test your methods that throws exceptions as mentioned in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from `JUnit5` `@Test` javadoc:

> @Test methods must not be private or static and must not return a value.

So you should remove the `static` keyword from them and the test should work properly.

Usually exception tests `throw` in some way the exception and validate if it was properly `thrown`. I see you are instantiating it and verifying if the message is as expected, but the best approach would be something like:

```
@Test
public void DepartmentMismatchException_Test() {
    Department testD = new Department("CSE 101","CSE 101!");
    Teacher testT = new Teacher("Mehmet", "mehmet.com", testD, "CV Mehmet");
    Course testC1 = new Course(testD,101,"Test Course 1","Test Course 1 Desc.",testT,6);
    String expMsg = "DepartmentMismatchException: Teacher in " + testT.getDepartment().getCode()+ ", Course in " +testC1.getDepartment().getCode();

    Exception thrownException = Assertions.assertThrows(DepartmentMismatchException.class, () -> /* Some code that throws your exception */);
    assertEquals(expMsg, thrownException.toString() /* or maybe thrownException.getMessage() */);
}
```

You can check a tutorial and more examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception).

Comment: In any case there should be thrown exception, right? I thought that i can create an exception object and reach their methods such as toString and use it with assertEquals. So this is a bad approaching.

Comment: You don't *need* to throw it, but usually you would go for it to be sure that if the exception follows the path it is supposed to follow (being thrown), it behaves has expected. Even though I think it would be better to test it where you use it, you could just do something like: `assertThrows(DepartmentMismatchException.class, () -> throw new DepartmentMismatchException(/*your parameters*/));` and then assert the message is as expected. Once again, I would not go for this approach, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming testT.getDepartment() will throw DME if yes, try using `org.junit.Rule`

```
@Rule
    public ExpectedException myExpectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test 
    public void DepartmentMismatchException_Test() {
        Department testD = new Department("CSE 101","CSE 101!");
        Teacher testT = new Teacher("Mehmet", "mehmet.com", testD, "CV Mehmet");
        Course testC1 = new Course(testD,101,"Test Course 1","Test Course 1 
        Desc.",testT,6);
        String expMsg = "DepartmentMismatchException: Teacher in " + 
        testT.getDepartment().getCode()+ ", Course in " 
        +testC1.getDepartment().getCode();
    
        testT.getDepartment(); // or any other st. which you expect it to throw DME
        myExpectedException.expect(DepartmentMismatchException .class);
        myExpectedException.expectMessage(expMsg);
    }
```

Comment: Actually nothing throw an exception in these codes. I just want to compare the message from DepartmentMismatchException's toString() method that student write it and the message that should be. (Assume i am teacher and students have assignment task list includes classes, attributes and methods )

Comment: I believe you must throw an exception in that test case, so that you can assert it's ex.toString()

Comment: never use Rule with Junit5: assertThrows is the way to check exceptions.
Moreover: even with JUnit4, starting from version 4.13, this way is already depricated.